Comparing the old value and new value of a GridView using '!=' is producing an unexpected result
I am comparing e.NewValues["Schedule"] != e.OldValues["Schedule"] in my testing, they are the same value but the if return true in code below, why is that?
private bool UpdateWaiveItemShortShipCheckingPass(GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    DateTime TargetReplenishmentSchedule;

    if (!DateTime.TryParse(TextBoxTargetReplenishmentSchedule.Text.Trim(), out TargetReplenishmentSchedule))
    {
        ShowJavaScriptMessage("TextBoxTargetReplenishmentScheduleIsNotDate", "Target Replenishment Schedule is not a date!");
        return false;
    }

    var oldTargetReplenishmentSchedule = e.OldValues["Schedule"];

    if (oldTargetReplenishmentSchedule != null)
    {
        var old = e.OldValues["Schedule"];
        var nnn = e.NewValues["Schedule"];

        if (e.NewValues["Schedule"] != e.OldValues["Schedule"])
        {
            if (TargetReplenishmentSchedule.Date < DateTime.Now.Date)
            {
                ShowJavaScriptMessage("invalidTargetReplenishmentSchedule", "Target Replenishment Schedule must be on or after today!");
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}


What's the e  and ["Schedule"] type addressed to?

Let me guess, it'd an object == object comparison?

@TấnNguyên e is GridViewUpdateEventArgs. ["Schedule"] is datetime?

If you are sure about data, take it as DateTime old, DateTime nnn and Compare only Date Part. Is there time in it ? Make sure it is also same in both

@HarshadRaval I am certain their values are the same, "2024-6-24" for both of them, I checked using breakpoint.
